# What is the difference between CfnTableProps and TableProps in CDK?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

In CDK, for most of the constructs, I can also find a Cfn variant of it. What is the difference? Eg. CfnTableProps and TableProps. Which is the one we should use generally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cfnxx` resources are low-level constructs.

"These constructs represent all of the AWS resources that are available in AWS CloudFormation."

As opposed to high-level constructs which "provide the same functionality, but handle much of the details, boilerplate, and glue logic required by CFN constructs".

More info available here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/constructs.html

Personally, I've used used these only when there's no API available in the high-level constructs for what I'm trying to achieve.